# How to make sure that app signing passwords are not available if someone decompiles the apk?

Tags: android, android-keystore, google-play-console, android-app-signing

Currently, I sign the app in the following manner where keys are read from env in CI.

```
signingConfigs {
  release {
      storeFile file(System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH"))
      storePassword System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
      keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
      keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
  }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "true"]
    }
}
```

But this method will make the passwords available if someone decompiles the apk.

Is there a way by which keys are only used during the signing and then stripped from code and then uploaded to Play store?

Or if someone can point me to more secure ways of signing apk's?

Comment: that info is not included to your apk. No one will ever get that info unless they took your keystore file and passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This details doesn't get bundled in a apk file, so even if someone de-compiles your apk he wont get to see this.

You can alternatively use android studio to create a signed apk.
Check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) link to see how it is done

Comment: This was happening due to `buildConfig.java` (which gets generated during build) somehow got picked up from environment data while build.